# star rating image not deploying to Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having a bit of an issue, I am using this plugin jQuery Raty (rating system), I have the star images on my assets/images folder but for some reason, the images are not showing. Any idea of what might be?

I already ran **rails assets:precompile**

because I found this answer here, but no dice.

It works fine on localhost, this is what the path looks like:

```js
<script>
  $('.review-rating').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    score: function(){
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    },
    path: '/assets'
  });
</script>

<script>
  $('.average-review-rating').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    path: '/assets',
    score: function(){
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
</script>
```

https://imdb-rails-app.herokuapp.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command **assets:precompile**, all the assets will be compiled and returned with a MD5 hash after file name like this:

```
#=> app/assets/images/one-star.png
$ rake assets:precompile
#=> public/assets/one-star-{MD5 Hash here}.png
```

That's why when you expect the star image URL looks like **your-domain.com/assets/one-star.png** then it simply does not work

From your snippet, I suppose you're using [jQuery Raty](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty) for rating, so the solution is letting Raty know your compiled star images by using its configuration + Rails asset helper

```
<!-- in your view.html.erb file -->
<script>
  $('.review-rating').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    score: function(){
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    },
    starOn: <%= "#{image_path('star-on.png')}" %>,
    starOff: <%= "#{image_path('star-off.png')}" %>,
    // Do the same with starHalf, cancelOn, cancelOff
  });
</script>
```

In this way, your Raty will know the correct way to load your star images.

You can read more about [Raty Options](https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty#options) and [Rails's asset helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path)